# i have a problem with python web scraping code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing some code that can keep me weekly updated on the news of a specific epic games store page, but for the moment I'm stuck in the html data scraping part of the site.

the code i wrote is this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://store.epicgames.com/it/free-games'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

this is the result:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <style>
   @media screen and (max-width:374px){h1{font-size:18px}.cf_challenge_container{margin:25px;padding:25px}.cf_challenge_text{font-size:16px}}@media screen and (min-width:375px) and (max-width:1279px){h1{font-size:30px}.cf_challenge_container{margin:25px;padding:60px}.cf_challenge_text{font-size:16px}}@media screen and (min-width:1280px){h1{font-size:40px}.cf_challenge_container{margin:25px;padding:60px}.cf_challenge_text{font-size:18px}}@media screen and (min-width:1920px){h1{font-size:50px}}.cf_challenge_text_small{font-size:11px}*,:after :before{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;box-sizing:border-box;text-size-adjust:100%}body{height:100vh;width:100vw;overflow-x:hidden;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;letter-spacing:.2px;color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);margin:0;background:#121212;display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-items:center}.logo{padding-bottom:25px}.logo,section{display:flex;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;text-align:center}h1,p{font-family:Brutal,sans-serif;font-weight:400;padding:0;margin:0}h1{line-height:34px;text-align:center;letter-spacing:-.5px;color:#fff;margin:0 0 20px}p{font-size:14px;line-height:20px;letter-spacing:.2px;color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.5)}strong{font-weight:400;color:#fff}.cf_challenge_container{max-width:430px;min-width:200px;background-color:#202020;font-family:sans-serif;line-height:normal;overflow:auto}.cf_challenge,.cf_challenge_container{display:flex;justify-content:center;flex-direction:column}.cf_challenge{text-align:center;margin:25px 0}.cf_challenge_container hr{border-bottom:0;max-width:500px;opacity:.25}.cf_close_button{background:transparent;border-radius:4px;color:#fff;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;position:absolute;right:15px;top:10px;transition:.1s}.cf_close_button:hover{background:#3b3b3b}.cf_error_container button{background:transparent;border:1px solid #000;border-radius:4px;color:#000;cursor:pointer;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:700;margin:5px;padding:14px 22px}.cf_error_container p{color:#000;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;margin:20px}.cf_error_container{align-items:flex-start;background:#ffa640;border-radius:4px;display:none;justify-content:space-between;margin:auto auto 8px;text-align:left;width:500px}.cf_logo{margin:0 auto;width:41px}
  </style>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   const localeStrings = {
            ar: {
                challengeTitle: 'خطوة واحدة إضافية',
                challengeSubtitle: 'يُرجى إكمال فحص الأمان للمتابعة',
                sessionId: 'مُعرّف الجلسة',
                ipAddress: 'عنوان IP',
            },
            de: {
                challengeTitle: 'Ein letzter Schritt',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Bitte führe eine Sicherheitskontrolle aus, um fortzufahren.',
                sessionId: 'Sitzungs-ID',
                ipAddress: 'IP-Adresse',
            },
            en: {
                challengeTitle: 'One More Step',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Please complete a security check to continue',
                sessionId: 'Session ID',
                ipAddress: 'IP Address',
            },
            'es-ES': {
                challengeTitle: 'Un paso más',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Completa el control de seguridad para continuar',
                sessionId: 'ID de sesión',
                ipAddress: 'Dirección IP',
            },
            'es-MX': {
                challengeTitle: 'Un paso más',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Completa el control de seguridad para continuar',
                sessionId: 'ID de sesión',
                ipAddress: 'Dirección IP',
            },
            fr: {
                challengeTitle: 'Encore une étape',
                challengeSubtitle: "Remplissez l'enquête de sécurité pour continuer",
                sessionId: 'ID de session',
                ipAddress: 'Adresse IP',
            },
            it: {
                challengeTitle: 'Ancora un passo da compiere',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Completa un controllo di sicurezza per continuare',
                sessionId: 'ID della sessione',
                ipAddress: 'Indirizzo IP',
            },
            ja: {
                challengeTitle: 'あともう1ステップ',
                challengeSubtitle: '継続するにはセキュリティチェックを完了してください',
                sessionId: 'セッションID',
                ipAddress: 'IPアドレス',
            },
            ko: {
                challengeTitle: '한 단계가 더 남았습니다',
                challengeSubtitle: '계속하려면 보안 검사를 완료해주세요',
                sessionId: '세션 ID',
                ipAddress: 'IP 주소',
            },
            pl: {
                challengeTitle: 'Jeszcze jeden krok',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Przeprowadź kontrolę bezpieczeństwa, by kontynuować',
                sessionId: 'Identyfikator sesji',
                ipAddress: 'Adres IP',
            },
            'pt-BR': {
                challengeTitle: 'Mais uma etapa',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Complete uma verificação de segurança para continuar',
                sessionId: 'ID da sessão',
                ipAddress: 'Endereço IP',
            },
            ru: {
                challengeTitle: 'Ещё один шаг',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Перед тем как продолжить, завершите проверку безопасности',
                sessionId: 'Идентификатор сеанса',
                ipAddress: 'IP-адрес',
            },
            th: {
                challengeTitle: 'อีกขั้นตอนเดียวเท่านั้น',
                challengeSubtitle: 'โปรดทำการตรวจสอบความปลอดภัยให้เสร็จเพื่อดำเนินการต่อ',
                sessionId: 'ID เซสชัน',
                ipAddress: 'ที่อยู่ IP',
            },
            tr: {
                challengeTitle: 'Son Bir Adım Daha',
                challengeSubtitle: 'Devam etmek için lütfen bir güvenlik kontrolünü tamamla',
                sessionId: 'Oturum NO',
                ipAddress: 'IP Adresi',
            },
            'zh-CN': {
                challengeTitle: '再进行一步操作',
                challengeSubtitle: '请完成安全检查以继续',
                sessionId: '会话 ID',
                ipAddress: 'IP 地址',
            },
            'zh-TW': {
                challengeTitle: '再一個步驟',
                challengeSubtitle: '請完成安全性確認以繼續',
                sessionId: '階段 ID',
                ipAddress: 'IP 位址',
            }
        }

        const getLocaleStrings = (locale = 'en') => {
            switch (locale.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'ar':
                    return localeStrings.ar;
                case 'de-de':
                case 'de':
                    return localeStrings.de;
                case 'en-us':
                case 'en':
                    return localeStrings.en;
                case 'es-es':
                    return localeStrings["es-ES"];
                case 'es-mx':
                    return localeStrings["es-MX"];
                case 'fr':
                case 'fr-fr':
                    return localeStrings.fr;
                case 'it':
                case 'it-it':
                    return localeStrings.it;
                case 'ja':
                case 'ja-jp':
                    return localeStrings.ja;
                case 'ko':
                case 'ko-kr':
                    return localeStrings.ko;
                case 'pl':
                    return localeStrings.pl;
                case 'pt':
                case 'pt-br':
                    return localeStrings["pt-BR"];
                case 'ru':
                case 'ru-ru':
                    return localeStrings.ru;
                case 'th':
                    return localeStrings.th;
                case 'tr':
                    return localeStrings.tr;
                case 'zh':
                case 'zh-cn':
                    return localeStrings["zh-CN"];
                case 'zh-tw':
                    return localeStrings["zh-TW"]
                default: {
                    const hyphIndex = locale.indexOf('-');
                    const localeSub = locale.substring(0, hyphIndex);
                    if (hyphIndex > -1) {
                        return getLocaleStrings(localeSub);
                    } else {
                        return localeStrings.en;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-t]');
            els.forEach((el) => {
                const tKey = el.getAttribute('data-t');
                const locale = window.navigator.language;
                const loc = getLocaleStrings(locale);
                el.innerText = loc[tKey];
            })
        });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="cf_challenge_container">
   <div class="cf_challenge_section">
    <div class="logo">
     <img alt="Epic Games Logo" class="cf_logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcKICAgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIgogICB3aWR0aD0iODgiCiAgIGhlaWdodD0iMTA0IgogICB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgODggMTA0IgogICBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJ0cnVlIgogICB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiPgogIDxwYXRoCiAgICAgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIKICAgICBkPSJNNy44OTYgMGg3Mi4yMDJjNS43NjcgMCA3Ljg5NiAyLjE3OCA3Ljg5NiA4LjA4MXY3MS4yMzJjMCAuNjcgMCA1LjI5LTQuNTI5IDcuNzMyLTMuMDIgMS42MjctMTQuODMyIDYuNjMzLTM1LjQzNyAxNS4wMTgtMS44Mi44NTQtMi42OTkgMS4wNzUtNC4wMyAxLjA1LTEuNDk2IDAtMi4wNTctLjIwMi00LjA1LTEuMDVDMTkuMzU3IDkzLjQwNyA3LjU1MSA4OC40IDQuNTMgODcuMDQ1IDAgODUuMDEuMjE1IDgyLjQ2NS4wODMgODEuMTc3QTE4Ljc4MSAxOC43ODEgMCAwIDEgMCA3OS4zMTNWOC4wODFDMCAyLjE3OCAyLjEyOSAwIDcuODk2IDB6bTY2LjA4OSA3Mi42MDRMNzQgNzIuNDN2LS4zODFsLS4wMTUtLjE3NC0uMDE3LS4xNTktLjA2NC0uMzE4LS4wMzItLjE0Mi0uMDQ3LS4xNDMtLjA1LS4xNDQtLjA2My0uMTI2LS4wODEtLjE0NC0uMDgxLS4xMjYtLjA5Ni0uMTQyLS4wOTYtLjEyOC0uMTEzLS4xMS0uMTEzLS4xMjgtLjEyOC0uMTExLS4xMjgtLjExMS0uMTMtLjA4LS4xMjgtLjA5Ni0uMTI4LS4wNzgtLjE0NS0uMDgtLjE0NS0uMDc5LS4xNi0uMDgtLjE2Mi0uMDY0LS4xNi0uMDgtLjE3Ny0uMDYtLjE0NS0uMDQ5LS4xNDQtLjA0OC0uMTYyLS4wNDYtLjE0NC0uMDQ4LS4xNi0uMDQ4LS4xNi0uMDQ4LS4xNjMtLjAzMi0uMTc3LS4wNDgtLjE2LS4wNDYtLjE3Ny0uMDMzLS4xNzctLjA0Ny0uMTc3LS4wNDgtLjE3Ny0uMDQ4LS4xNi0uMDMxLS4xNDUtLjA0OC0uMTQ1LS4wMzItLjEyOC0uMDQ4LS4xMjgtLjAzMS0uMTk0LS4wNjMtLjE3Ny0uMDY1LS4xNi0uMDYzLS4xMjgtLjA3OS0uMTQ3LS4wOC0uMTExLS4xMS0uMDY2LS4wOTUtLjA3OS0uMTc1LS4wMTctLjIwNnYtLjAzM2wuMDE3LS4xNTcuMDY0LS4xNDQuMDk2LS4xNDMuMTQ1LS4xMjcuMTEzLS4wNjMuMTI4LS4wNjMuMTQ1LS4wMzIuMTYyLS4wMzMuMTc1LS4wMzFoLjM1NGwuMTQ1LjAxNi4xNjIuMDE1LjE2LjAxNy4xNi4wMzEuMTYuMDMyLjE2Mi4wMzEuMTYuMDQ4LjE2Mi4wNDguMTc2LjA0OC4xMy4wNjMuMTQ0LjA0OC4xMjguMDYzLjE0NS4wNjMuMTI5LjA2NS4xNDUuMDYzLjEyOC4wOC4xNDUuMDYyLjEzLjA5Ni4xMjcuMDguMTQ0LjA3OS4xMy4wOTUuMDk2LS4xMjYuMDgtLjEyOC4wOTctLjEyNy4wOTYtLjEyNi4wOTYtLjE0NC4wOC0uMTI2LjA5Ny0uMTI4LjA5OC0uMTI3LjA3OS0uMTI2LjA5Ni0uMTI4LjA5OC0uMTI3LjA4LS4xMjYuMDk1LS4xNDQuMDk4LS4xMjYuMDk2LS4xMjguMDgtLjEyNy4wOTctLjEyOC0uMTI4LS4wOTQtLjEyOC0uMDk1LS4xMy0uMDk2LS4xMjgtLjA4LS4xNDUtLjA5NC0uMTI4LS4wOC0uMTQ1LS4wNzktLjE0NS0uMDgtLjEyOC0uMDY0LS4xNDUtLjA3OC0uMTYyLS4wNjQtLjE0NC0uMDYzLS4xNDUtLjA2My0uMTQ0LS4wNDgtLjE2Mi0uMDY1LS4xNDQtLjAzMS0uMTQ1LS4wNDgtLjE2MS0uMDQ3LS4xNDQtLjAzMS0uMTYxLS4wMzMtLjE2LS4wMzItLjE0Ni0uMDMxLS4xNi0uMDMyLS4xNzctLjAxNi0uMTYtLjAzMi0uMTc4LS4wMTVoLS4xNmwtLjE3OC0uMDE2LS4xNzctLjAxN2gtLjY5bC0uMzIxLjAzMy0uMTYyLjAxNS0uMTYuMDE3LS4xNDUuMDMxLS4xNi4wMzItLjE0Ny4wMzEtLjE0My4wMzItLjEyOC4wMzMtLjE0Ny4wNDYtLjE2LjA2NS0uMTYuMDQ2LS4xNDUuMDY1LS4xNDUuMDgtLjE0NS4wNjItLjE0NS4wOC0uMTI4LjA4LS4xMjguMDk0LS4xMy4wOTYtLjExMS4wOC0uMTMuMTEtLjExMS4xMjgtLjExMy4xMS0uMTEzLjEyNy0uMDk2LjEyNy0uMDk2LjEyOC0uMDgxLjE0Mi0uMDguMTQzLS4wNjUuMTQ0LS4wNjQuMTQyLS4wNjQuMTQzLS4wMzIuMTQyLS4wNS4xNDQtLjA2My4yODUtLjAxNy4xNi0uMDE1LjE0Mi0uMDE3LjE1OXYuMzY2bC4wMTcuMTczLjAxNS4xNi4wMTcuMTU4LjAzMi4xNDMuMDMyLjE1OS4wNDkuMTI2LjA0Ny4xNDQuMDQ5LjEyNi4wNjQuMTEuMDguMTQzLjA4LjEyOC4wOC4xMS4wOTcuMTEyLjA5OC4xMS4xMTEuMTEyLjExMy4xMS4xMTMuMDk3LjEyOC4wOC4xMy4wOTQuMTQzLjA4LjEzLjA3OS4xNi4wOC4xNDUuMDc5LjE2LjA2My4xNjIuMDY0LjE2LjA2My4xNzcuMDYzLjE0NS4wNDguMTQ1LjA0OC4xNDMuMDQ4LjE2Mi4wMzIuMTQ1LjA0OC4xNi4wNDYuMTYuMDMyLjE2Mi4wNDguMTYuMDMxLjE3Ny4wNDguMTYyLjAzMi4xNzUuMDQ4LjE2Mi4wMzEuMTYuMDQ4LjE0NS4wMzIuMTQ1LjA0OC4xMjguMDMxLjExMy4wMzIuMTkzLjA3OS4xNjEuMDY1LjE0NS4wNjMuMTI4LjA2My4xMjkuMDk2LjExMi4wOTQuMDgxLjExMS4wNjQuMTU5LjAxNy4xOXYuMDMybC0uMDE3LjE1OS0uMDQ4LjE0Mi0uMDY0LjEyOC0uMDk3LjExLS4xMjguMDk3LS4xMTMuMDYzLS4xMy4wNDgtLjE0My4wMzEtLjE0NS4wMzItLjE2MS4wMzEtLjE3Ny4wMTdoLS4zNTNsLS4xNzctLjAxN2gtLjE2bC0uMTYyLS4wMzEtLjE3Ny0uMDE1LS4xNi0uMDMzLS4xNi0uMDMyLS4xNjItLjAzMS0uMTQ1LS4wNDgtLjE2LS4wNDctLjE2LS4wNDgtLjE0Ny0uMDYzLS4xNDMtLjA0OC0uMTQ1LS4wNjQtLjE0NS0uMDYzLS4xNDUtLjA2My0uMTI4LS4wOC0uMTQ1LS4wNjMtLjEyOC0uMDgtLjE0NS0uMDk1LS4xMy0uMDgtLjE0My0uMDk0LS4xMy0uMDk2LS4xNDMtLjA5Ni0uMTMtLjA5NS0uMDk2LjEyOC0uMTEzLjExMS0uMDk2LjEyNy0uMTEzLjEyNi0uMDk2LjExMS0uMDk2LjEyOC0uMTEzLjEyNy0uMDk2LjExMS0uMTEzLjEyNi0uMDk2LjExMy0uMTEzLjEyNi0uMDk2LjEyNy0uMDk2LjExMS0uMTEzLjEyOC0uMDk2LjEyNi0uMTEzLjExLS4wOTYuMTI4LjEyOC4xMTEuMTEzLjA5Ni4xMjguMDk1LjEyOC4wOTYuMTMuMDk0LjEyOC4wOTYuMTI4LjA4LjEyOC4wOC4xNDcuMDc5LjEyOC4wNzguMTQzLjA4LjE0Ny4wNjQuMTQzLjA3OC4xNDUuMDYzLjE0NS4wNjQuMTYuMDYzLjE0NS4wNDguMTYuMDQ4LjE0NS4wNjMuMTYyLjA0OC4xNi4wNDcuMTQ1LjAzMy4xNi4wNDYuMTYyLjAzMy4xNi4wMzIuMzIyLjA2My4xNi4wMTYuMTYyLjAzMi4xNzUuMDE1LjE2Mi4wMTYuMTYuMDE3aC4xNzdsLjE2LjAxNWguNjc2bC4xNi0uMDE1LjE3OC0uMDE3LjE2MS0uMDE2LjE0NS0uMDE1LjE2LS4wMTcuMTYyLS4wMzEuMTQ0LS4wMzIuMTQ1LS4wMzEuMTYtLjAzMi4xNDYtLjA0OC4xNi0uMDQ4LjE2LS4wNDguMTYtLjA2My4xNjMtLjA2My4xNDQtLjA4LjE0NC0uMDY0LjE0Ni0uMDguMTI5LS4wOTQuMTI4LS4wNzguMTI4LS4wOTYuMTEzLS4wOTQuMTI4LS4xMTMuMDk2LS4wOTQuMTEzLS4xMTEuMDk2LS4xMTEuMDgtLjEyOC4wOTctLjEyNy4xNjItLjI1NC4wNjQtLjE0Mi4wNjQtLjEyOC4wNjQtLjE0Mi4wNDktLjE2LjAzMi0uMTQyLjA0Ny0uMTU5LjAzNC0uMTU5LjAxNS0uMTc0LjAxNy0uMTU5em0tMTEuMjc3IDMuMTc0aC4xNjJ2LTIuNjE5aC02LjMwM3YtMS45NjdoNS41OTV2LTIuNDZoLTUuNTk1di0xLjg5aDYuMjIydi0yLjYyaC05LjI5M3YxMS41NTZoOS4yMTJ6bS0xMS43NDYgMGguMTZWNjQuMjIyaC0zLjI5NWwtLjA4MS4xMjctLjA4LjE0My0uMDk3LjEyNi0uMDgxLjE0NC0uMDguMTI2LS4wOC4xNDQtLjA5Ni4xMjYtLjA4MS4xNDItLjA4MS4xMjgtLjA4LjEyNi0uMDk2LjE0Mi0uMDguMTI4LS4wODEuMTQyLS4wODEuMTI4LS4wOTUuMTQtLjA4LjEyOC0uMDgyLjEyOC0uMDguMTQtLjA4LjEyOC0uMDk2LjE0My0uMDguMTI3LS4wODIuMTQxLS4wOC4xMjgtLjA5Ny4xNDItLjA3OS4xMjYtLjA4LjEyOC0uMDgyLjE0Mi0uMDk2LjEyOC0uMDguMTQyLS4wOC4xMjYtLjA4LjE0NC0uMDk3LjEyNi0uMDguMTQyLS4wODIuMTI4LS4wNzktLjEyOC0uMD
```

or from what I seem to understand a kind of page that asks in several languages for a further security check which I doubt is the desired result since the classes I am looking for are not there; among other things I have the link open and clicking f12 the result is quite another thing, then since I'm quite new to html I don't even know if the result I want to get from my code must be the same as what I see from site and f12 open.

in any case I would like to know your opinion about it and if i am in a sort of security check automatically made by the site there is a way to get around it, thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this site somehow understands that you want to open it in "unusual way" using automated script, not from a browser. I don't really know how this is implemented on server side, but try to look at the HTTP headers of the request in your debug console in the browser (F12). You may need additional headers, not only "User-Agent". At least try to add "Host" header.

Comment: @Roman sorry for the late answer, but i still have trouble finding the host header on chrome: i went on my debug console, i selected the network tab, refreshed the site page disabling cache in order to see full headers, but i didn't saw any host header; however, when doing the same thing on firefox, it did show an host header: "store.epicgames.com" wich correspond to the :authority: header i saw in chrome althought, with a quick research, i saw they are not the same thing. should i use the header found in firefox even though i dont understand why it isn't shown in my chrome console?